# Why can't I get water out of my washing machine taps?

Tags: plumbing, water, washing-machine

I just moved in and ordered a new washer/dryer that were installed on Monday. There doesn't seem to be any water running to the washing machine. I unattached the hoses from the taps, tried turning the taps to different positions, and can't get water out of them. All nearby valves are on, and I can get water out of a pipe on the same line as the cold water after the black valve but before the taps.

I have photos of the lines here:
[image: Lines from valve]
[image: Corner image]
[image: water taps]

Any idea on what to check?

Comment: Not freezing in the basement right? Also, what about a shut off further back? Also, righty tighty, lefty loosey; you sure you have the round gate valve turned counter clockwise fully?

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Those odd-looking "pipe connections" appear to "Sharkbite" fittings (or something similar)

Comment: Every shut off I have seen is open, and I can get water out of pipes on the same line. It is freezing outside, but the basement isn't.

@mike65535 Are those significant at all? Do they have a way to turn off/on or something?

Comment: @Cole - no, they are simply solder-less connectors.  Way more expensive than the solder type but fairly effective in my experience.  Looks like most of the run to the washer area is using them (the elbows for ex. look like Sharkbites but you didn't circle them)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSeanround gate is definitely fully counter-clockwise. I wonder if a pipe or tap is clogged somewhere?

Comment: Double-check that the pipe isn't frozen. Looks like they are near an outside door (confirm?) and a slight draft could freeze the pipe but not make the basement seem overly cold.

Comment: If there are shut offs further up stream you can turn them off and then remove the sharkbite elbows nearest the washing machine valves. You can then have someone  briefly turn on the valves that you shut off to check if water is flowing. This will tell you if it is the washing machine valves or not.  The sharkbites can be removed by pushing the orange part into the fitting while pulling the fitting of the pipe, this can be tricky. there is a special tool for this but you can do it with crescent wrench if you size it just right .  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIvybegPxGY

Comment: @Alaskaman yup, seems like that was the issue. We had someone remove the shark bite connector (straight, not elbow) and it was blocked, wouldn’t allow anything in. He’s soldering on a regular coupling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are shut offs further up stream you can turn them off and then remove the sharkbite elbows nearest the washing machine valves. You can then have someone briefly turn on the valves that you shut off to check if water is flowing. This will tell you if it is the washing machine valves or not.

The sharkbites can be removed by pushing the orange part into the fitting while pulling the fitting of the pipe, this can be tricky. there is a special tool for this but you can do it with crescent wrench if you size it just right . 
[youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=nIvybegPxGY)